# Using.divide to band math and output image is one color image using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, hyperspectral-sensor

When i used the.divide function to a previous substract of bands, my output result in the Map.addLayer is a totally full green square in the previously defined geometry.
I've used this similar code to a Landsat 5 TM TOA collection and it goes perfect, but i'm getting a lot of trouble with Landsat 7, 8 and sentinel2A.

Here is my script:

```
var IMGLandsat7 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1')
  .filterDate('2000-10-01', '2001-04-30')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'Less_Than', 5);
var Landsat7Filtro = ee.Image(IMGLandsat7.max());
var Landsat7Clip = Landsat7Filtro.clip(geometry);

//BANDAS FECHA 1
var b1_1 = Landsat7Clip.select('B1');
var b2_1 = Landsat7Clip.select('B2');
var b3_1 = Landsat7Clip.select('B3');
var b4_1 = Landsat7Clip.select('B4');
var b5_1 = Landsat7Clip.select('B5');
//var b6_1 = Landsat7Clip.select('B6');
var b7_1 = Landsat7Clip.select('B7');

//VALORES MAXIMOS F1
//B1
var b11m = b1_1.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});
var b11Max = b11m.get('B1');
//B2
var b21m = b2_1.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});
var b21Max = b21m.get('B2');
//B3
var b31m = b3_1.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});
var b31Max = b31m.get('B3');
//B4
var b41m = b4_1.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});
var b41Max = b41m.get('B4');
//B5
var b51m = b5_1.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});
var b51Max = b51m.get('B5');
//B6
//var b61m = b6_1.reduceRegion({
//  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
//scale: 30,
//maxPixels: 1e10
//});
//var b61Max = b61m.get('B6');
//B7
var b71m = b7_1.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});
var b71Max = b71m.get('B7');

// Imagen Landsat 7 en la fecha 2

var IMGLandsat72 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1')
  .filterDate('2010-10-01', '2011-04-30')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'Less_Than', 5);
var Landsat7Filtro2 = ee.Image(IMGLandsat72.max());
var Landsat7Clip2 = Landsat7Filtro2.clip(geometry);

//BANDAS FECHA 2
var b1_2 = Landsat7Clip2.select('B1');
var b2_2 = Landsat7Clip2.select('B2');
var b3_2 = Landsat7Clip2.select('B3');
var b4_2 = Landsat7Clip2.select('B4');
var b5_2 = Landsat7Clip2.select('B5');
var b7_2 = Landsat7Clip2.select('B7');

//VALORES MAXIMOS F2
//B1
var b12m = b1_2.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});
var b12Max = b12m.get('B1');
//B2
var b22m = b2_2.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});
var b22Max = b22m.get('B2');
//B3
var b32m = b3_2.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});
var b32Max = b32m.get('B3');
//B4
var b42m = b4_2.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});
var b42Max = b42m.get('B4');
//B5
var b52m = b5_2.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});
var b52Max = b52m.get('B5');
//B7
var b72m = b7_2.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});
var b72Max = b72m.get('B7');

// Definición de maximo valor de banda al cuadrado
//B1
var num1 = ee.List([ee.Number(b11Max), ee.Number(b12Max)]);
var max_total1 = num1.reduce(ee.Reducer.max());
var square1 = ee.Number(max_total1).multiply(max_total1);
//B2
var num2 = ee.List([ee.Number(b21Max), ee.Number(b22Max)]);
var max_total2 = num2.reduce(ee.Reducer.max());
var square2 = ee.Number(max_total2).multiply(max_total2);
//B3
var num3 = ee.List([ee.Number(b31Max), ee.Number(b32Max)]);
var max_total3 = num3.reduce(ee.Reducer.max());
var square3 = ee.Number(max_total3).multiply(max_total3);
//B4
var num4 = ee.List([ee.Number(b41Max), ee.Number(b42Max)]);
var max_total4 = num4.reduce(ee.Reducer.max());
var square4 = ee.Number(max_total4).multiply(max_total4);
//B5
var num5 = ee.List([ee.Number(b51Max), ee.Number(b52Max)]);
var max_total5 = num5.reduce(ee.Reducer.max());
var square5 = ee.Number(max_total5).multiply(max_total5);
//B6
//var num6 = ee.List([ee.Number(b61Max), ee.Number(b62Max)]);
//var max_total6 = num6.reduce(ee.Reducer.max());
//var square6 = ee.Number (max_total6).multiply(max_total6);
//B7
var num7 = ee.List([ee.Number(b71Max), ee.Number(b72Max)]);
var max_total7 = num7.reduce(ee.Reducer.max());
var square7 = ee.Number(max_total7).multiply(max_total7);


// Definición de diferencias dividido maximo valor de banda al cuadrado
var b1difrcv = b1_1.subtract(b1_2).divide(square1);
var b2difrcv = b2_1.subtract(b2_2).divide(square2);
var b3difrcv = b3_1.subtract(b3_2).divide(square3);
var b4difrcv = b4_1.subtract(b4_2).divide(square4);
var b5difrcv = b5_1.subtract(b5_2).divide(square5);
var b7difrcv = b7_1.subtract(b7_2).divide(square7);

// sumatoria 
var rcvmax = b1difrcv.add(b2difrcv.add(b3difrcv.add(b4difrcv.add(b5difrcv.add(b7difrcv)))));

/Visualizacion
Map.addLayer(rcvmax, {
  min: -1,
  max: 1,
  palette: bdif_palette
});
```

everything goes fine, but when I get to the "// Definición de diferencias dividido maximo valor de banda al cuadrado" part, the result of that division is a fully green square (like the attached picture), like if there wasn't any spectral change in time.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel said, reduce the image value range that color needs to stretch between. You only get 256 levels of color for each of red, green, and blue, so if the range you set as `min` and `max` extends way outside the range of your data, the number of colors to describe it are very little - low contrast. A good way to determine what to set the `min` and `max` parameters at is to open the "Visualization parameters" for the image and set the stretch to 2 standard deviations or 98% and click apply. The values will be calculated and populate the input boxes, copy and paste them as your `min` and `max` parameter arguments or click the "Import" button to load them into your script as a dictionary.

[image]

Comment: thank you! I really appreciate

Comment: Justin, another question, How should I interpret or perform when the min and max that throw the configuration at any stretch value are 0-0?

Comment: Is it possible that the data are all 0?

Answer (score 0):

You do have a change between your points in time. I believe the problem is that they are fairly small, and don't show up unless you specify min/max in your visualisation parameters.

```
Map.addLayer(b1difrcv, {min: -0.001, max: 0.001}, 'b1difrcv')
Map.addLayer(b2difrcv, {min: -0.001, max: 0.001}, 'b2difrcv')
Map.addLayer(b3difrcv, {min: -0.001, max: 0.001}, 'b3difrcv')
Map.addLayer(b4difrcv, {min: -0.001, max: 0.001}, 'b4difrcv')
Map.addLayer(b5difrcv, {min: -0.001, max: 0.001}, 'b5difrcv')
Map.addLayer(b7difrcv, {min: -0.001, max: 0.001}, 'b7difrcv')
Map.addLayer(rcvmax, {min: -0.007, max: 0.007}, rcvmax);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f788bce8ae1bc92951a0c98651b77833

Comment: thank you! I really appreciate